# Retrieve Java string from Android drawable resource name

Tags: java, android

I have an array of drawable png files like this :

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.alabama, R.drawable.alaska, R.drawable.arizona};

currentImage++;
currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
```

How can I get something like this:

```
String imageName = "alabama"
```

I tried this, but it returns my Image View id instead of the src name.

```
String imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.idImageViewPic);
```

**UPDATE**
This is more of my code to get things in context. I have adapted an answer below, but i get an error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int.

```
public class GameFragment extends Fragment {

    private AlertDialog mDialog;
    private ImageView hImageViewPic;
    private Button iButton, gButton;

    private int currentImage = 0;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.alabama, R.drawable.alaska, R.drawable.arizona};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
        hImageViewPic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
        iButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.guess_button);

        final EditText responseField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ResponseText);



        // Handle buttons here...
        View guessButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.guess_button);
        guessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int score = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                String response = responseField.getText().toString();
                String wrongTextAnnouncement = getString(R.string.wrong_text, response);

                int resourceId = images[currentImage];
                String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
                hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
                hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
                String imageName = hImageViewPic.getTag(name);

                Log.d("UT3", response);
                Log.d("UT3", wrongTextAnnouncement);
                Log.d("UT3", imageName);
                if (imageName != response) {
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.wrong_title);
                    builder.setMessage(wrongTextAnnouncement);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    // nothing
                                }
                            });
                    mDialog = builder.show();
                } else {
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.right_title);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.right_text);
                    builder.setCancelable(false);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,
                                                    int i) {
                                    // nothing
                                }
                            });
                    score += 10;
                    String scoreString = String.valueOf(score);
                    Log.d("UT3", scoreString);
                }
                mDialog = builder.show();
                currentImage++;
                currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
                hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opnion this is better you use array of string images name like:

```
String[] imagesTitle = {alabama, alaska,arizona};
```

then get id of images like:

```
String imageName = imagesTitle[currentImage];
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable", this.getPackageName())
```

Where "this" is an Activity, written just to clarify.
then you can set tag for image and set id for your imageview like:

```
hImageViewPic.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
hImageViewPic.setTag(imageName);
```

I hope this can help!

Comment: Do you mean String[] imagesTitle = {"alabama", ...} ?

Comment: excuse me , what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving id of View because you are passing id of View to

```
getResourceEntryName(int resid)
```

If you want to get `String imageName = "alabama"` pass to method id of drawable, not ImageView

But there is no way to check what resource id was set to image view because under the hood **Drawable** was created from passed id.

Fortunately you can use `hImageViewPic.setTag(Object object)` to read it later.

So the code may look like:

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.alabama, R.drawable.alaska, R.drawable.arizona};

currentImage++;
currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
int resourceId = images[currentImage];
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resourceId);
hImageViewPic.setImageResource(resourceId);
hImageViewPic.setTag(name);
```

Later you can get the name of image by using: `hImageViewPic.getTag()`

Comment: I tested your code, but I must not have set it up right because I get an error. See edits.

Comment: Your provided code is full of mistakes, like comparing two Strings with = instead of equals. But major error is that you used `getTag(name)`, not `getTag()`. This does not even compile, in my opinion you should learn basics of Java first and then move to Android.